# How to recover RAID0 with MegaCli64?

Tags: raid

I have a RAID0 drive consisted of two SSDs. I accidentally removed one SSD and insert it back immediately. How can I recover the data?

I marked the reinserted disk as good and cleared the foriegn state. But I don't know how to add it back to the RAID group. The info of the reinserted disk:

```
Enclosure Device ID: 12
Slot Number: 23
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 30
WWN: 5002538e4062d3d4
Sequence Number: 7
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 3.638 TB [0x1d1c0beb0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 3.637 TB [0x1d1b0beb0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 3.637 TB [0x1d1b00000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Logical Sector Size:  512
Physical Sector Size:  512
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: 1B6Q
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5003048018219027
Connected Port Number: 0(path0)
Inquiry Data: S3YSNB0K800520R     Samsung SSD 860 EVO 4TB                 RVT01B6Q
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Link Speed: 12.0Gb/s
Media Type: Solid State Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature :28C (82.40 F)
PI Eligibility:  No
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Drive's NCQ setting : Enabled
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No
```

Here is the info of the RAID0:

```
DISK GROUP: 3
Number of Spans: 1
SPAN: 0
Span Reference: 0x04
Number of PDs: 2
Number of VDs: 1
Number of dedicated Hotspares: 0
Virtual Drive Information:
Virtual Drive: 4 (Target Id: 4)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-0, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size                : 7.276 TB
Sector Size         : 512
Is VD emulated      : No
Parity Size         : 0
State               : Offline
Strip Size          : 256 KB
Number Of Drives    : 2
Span Depth          : 1
Default Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAhead, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAhead, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Default Access Policy: Read/Write
Current Access Policy: Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Disk's Default
Encryption Type     : None
Bad Blocks Exist: No
PI type: No PI
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's rather for serverfault or superuser (doesn't have direct relation to UNIX/Linux).

Comment: I found a similar question in serverfault and solved this question. Can some admin move this question to serverfault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem using a trick from https://serverfault.com/a/779381.
The author said:

> There is a trick to get your data back - just recreate RAID 0 with the same parameters as you had earlier and when it asks you to Initialize the array just say NO.

Mark the reinserted physical drive as good

```
MegaCli64 -PDMakeGood -PhysDrv [12:23] -aALL
```

Clear the foreign mark:

```
MegaCli64 -CfgForeign -Clear -aALL
```

Delete the original RAID 0 virtual drive (in my case, it's virtual drive 4):

```
MegaCli64 -CfgLdDel -L4 -a0
```

Recreate RAID 0 drive with the same config:

```
MegaCli64 -CfgLdAdd -r0 [12:12,12:23] WB Direct -a0
```